# Two robots in an infinite line

Tags: algorithm

This is a little bit different from the "Parachuted Robots" puzzle. There are two robots hanging on an infinite line. Their distance is not relative, therefore it doesn't matter if they are 5m or 5km apart. Suppose that you need to program the two robots in order to meet at the magnet and the only options you have are:

- One move to the left
- One move to the right
- Two moves to the left
- Two moves to the right
- Stop and check if the robot is on the magnet

The robots will not know if there are already next to the magnet, and moving one robot will also move the other robot on the same direction. Formulate an algorithm for the two robots to meet at the magnet.

I am unable to formulate a solution to this question, is there a solution to the puzzle?

Comment: How can they ever meet if they always move in the same direction? Doesn't this imply that their initial distance is preserved?

Comment: @NicoSchertler That is what was asked to, I am also confused with the question

Answer (score 1):

I think both robots can run the same program:

```
var steps = 10, count = 10, left = true;
while (!isRobotOnMagnet()) {
    if (count-- > 0)
        if (left)
            oneMoveLeft();
        else
            oneMoveRight();
    else {
        steps *= 2;
        left = !left;
        count = steps;
    }
}
```

Not the most elegant way to formulate it, there is room for improvement. The idea is go some steps to the left then double the amount to the right, then again double the amount to the left and so on... you will eventually find the magnet.

Comment: Yes that is correct the robots can run the same program

Comment: How are the robots going to meet at the magnet? Only one would touch it but not both with your answer right?

Comment: No eventually both will end up at the magnet because the robot stops when it is on the magnet but the other keeps running. They run the same program but each on its own computer.

Comment: The other will keep on running until it reaches the magnet? Isn't that the other robot at the magnet will move?